# Adding two fragments to the backstack within host Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I currently have an Android `Activity` called `MainActivity` that hosts 2 `Fragments` (Fragment A and Fragment B) via the code below.  I'm using a `TabLayout` to navigate back and forth between `Fragment` A and `Fragment` B within `MainActivity`.  Each `Fragment` includes a `listView` in addition to an `onItemClick` method.  Once the item in the `listView` is clicked within both `Fragment` A and `Fragment` B the user is taken to a new `Activity` (Activity_1 and Activity_2 respectively.  I need to override the back `button` in `Activity` 2, so that I'm taken back to `Fragment` B within the `MainActivity`. I'm having difficulty understanding where and how to add both `Fragment` A and `Fragment` B to the `backstack`, thus allowing me to hit the back `button` in Activity_1 and Activity_2 that takes me back to the `Fragment` that I navigated from. Where and how do I implement the `backstack` code for Fragment A and Fragment B in the `MainActivity`.

[image: Fragments]

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TabLayout tabLayout;
ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getApplicationContext()));

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

}
private class CustomAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

    private String fragments [] = {"Fragments 1", "Fragments 2"};

    public CustomAdapter(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager, Context applicationContext){
        super(supportFragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch(position){
            case 0:
                return  new Fragment1();
            case 1:
                return  new Fragment2();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.length;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return fragments[position];
    }
  }
}
```

FragmentA.java

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragA, container, false);
}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    . . .

   }
}
```

FragmentB.java

```
FragmentA.java

public class FragmentB extends Fragment {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragB, container, false);
}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    . . .

   }
}
```

Comment: How about open new avtivity as a dialog ?

Comment: Inside `MainActivity` save currently visible fragment/tab and navigate to that tab when `onStart` is called. And if you'll use `ViewPager` this will be automatically happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can start the new activities using startActivityForResult() and return a constant based on which activity you are on and handle the response in you MainActivity and display the fragment you want.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your MainActivity knows (or can know) which fragment (A or B) handled click:

1. MainActivity should store state (information re which fragment handled click)
2. Once restored, MainActivity should recreate UI based on saved state
3. Neither Activity1 nor Activity2 should know anything about invocator - they could finish by "up" or sys back, does not matter

In case you are using FragmentStatePagerAdapter (or similar) to serve your tabs, it's even more simple.